# moment generating function technique

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

If $X$ was a random variable with a distribution $\mathrm{Normal} ( 0, 1 )$, using moment generating function technique we have to show that $Y= X^2$ has the Chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.
My problem is that I am used to solving such questions when $Y$ is a linear transformation of $X$! This is my first time to face such a question.

Comment: transform the mgf of the normal distribution using $y=x^2$, show that it becomes the mgf of the new distribution

Comment: @user130512 i know!! this is how I'm supposed to solve. But the problem arise cause I'm not familiar to distribute the expectation for the non linear cases.

Comment: are you allowed to use the gamma distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for the calculation we will need the well-known result that
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} \; dx = \sqrt{\pi/a}
$$
when $a>0$.  Also, in general we have that if $X$ is a random variable with
density function $f(x)$ then, for any function $h$ of $X$ we have
$$
   \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
   \E \left( h(X) \right) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x) f(x) \, dx.
$$
Calculating the moment-generating function of $X^2$ when $X$ have the standard normal distribution:
$$
\begin{align}
   \phi_{X^2}(t) &= \E \left( e^{tX^2} \right)  \\
       &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \; dx \\
      &=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(1/2-t)x^2} \; dx \\
      &=  (1-2t)^{-1/2}.
\end{align}
$$
when $t<1/2$.  That you can compare with the moment-generating function of the chi-squared distribution (with one degree of freedom).  Unicity of moment-generating functions yield the result.

Comment: thank you I will compare it first with the Gamma( 1/2,2) which is Chi-square (1) :)